# kong Laravel integration

Tags: php, laravel-5, kong

We have installed kong in ubuntu server. When we try to call lumen api via Kong, it returns 404. Kong works fine when calling APIs created using core php. Is there any restriction with Kong and Laravel integration?

Comment: Kong works fine with Laravel, can you share your kong api config?

Comment: How you rung the API?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you consume the kong api from a blade template you must add 'OPTIONS' method in your route (kong 0.14) or api(kong <= 0.13) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

What web server you are serving your Laravel application ? Nginx + PHP-FPM ?

Kong is API Gateway and Reverse Proxy. You have to serve your laravel application with nginx or apache, HA Proxy then put it behind Kong.